# searching for value in Dataframe: set value for column like value of compared dataframe if exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey i have the following question: How can i search a value of a dataframe(1) in another dataframe(2) and if it is found i want to set a value of dataframe(1) to a value of dataframe (2).

Example:

df1:

```
   ID      contract-nr.
   +         bc7
   +         bx9
   +         df4
```

df2:

```
 code      nr1         nr2        nr3
 1133      k2f         bx9        h3d
 1222      df4         gp7        kl9
 1456      rs6         ks0        bc7
```

result of df1:

```
  ID      contract-nr.
 1456        bc7
 1133        bx9
 1222        df4
```

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: Do you mean  match the column `contract-nr.` values with df2,  what is expected output?

Comment: the expected output is under the df2. Its result of df1. So i wanna match contract nr. with values of df2 and then set value of ID equal to value of code.

Comment: I feel it is better to have the adding inputs in question will be more better for others to get copy. You can try `df1.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID' : ['+','+','+'],
    'contract-nr' : ['bc7','bx9','df4'],
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame((['1133','k2f','bx9','h3d'],['1222','df4','gp7','kl9'],['1456','rs6','ks0','bc7']),columns=
                  ['code','nr1','nr2','nr3'])
def apply_func(x):
    b = (df2[['nr1','nr2','nr3']]==x).any(axis=1)
    return df2.loc[b[b].index[0]]['code']
df1['ID'] = df1['contract-nr'].apply(apply_func)
print(df1)
```

**Method 2**

```
df1['ID'] = df1['contract-nr'].apply(lambda x : list(df2[(df2[['nr1','nr2','nr3']]==x).any(axis=1)]['code'])[0])
```

**Method 3**

```
df1['ID'] = df1['contract-nr'].apply(lambda x : df2[(df2[['nr1','nr2','nr3']]==x).any(axis=1)]['code'].iloc[0])
```

**Output**

```
    ID  contract-nr
0   1456    bc7
1   1133    bx9
2   1222    df4
```